# Precharge Control for EV

Tags: control, electric-vehicle, pre-charge

I have a conventional precharging system consisting of a contactor and a resistor. What kind of way should I follow to control this with analog circuit elements in electric vehicles? Do you know a way? Or is there a sample project that I can review as a reference?

Comment: I'm sure you think you know what an EV is, since you're building one.  But there are many other kinds. Need to know more about your vehicle.If you're using J1772 or Mennekes, a bunch of other requirements kick in, and analog isn't going to cut it.